# ThinkingSphinx using RSpec, error: "Failed to start searchd daemon." 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thinking-sphinx

I have a problem with running Sphinx in test

As that was shown in the example 
[ThinkingSphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/testing.html)

I start the test with **ThinkingSphinx::Test.start** and end with **ThinkingSphinx::Test.stop**

The head section of test file contains

**require 'thinking_sphinx/test'**

**ThinkingSphinx::Test.init**

The error is

Failed to start searchd daemon. Check ...searchd.log.

Do you familiar with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you running Sphinx already in development? And if so, do you have [a different port setting](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/advanced_config.html) for the test environment in `config/sphinx.yml`? If not, then you'll need to do that, to ensure you can have two daemons running at once.

Comment: great now it runs, but doesn't work. Sphinx doesn't see new records. I have ThinkingSphinx::Test.start at the begging of the test, ThinkingSphinx::Test.stop at the end, and ThinkingSphinx::Test.index after adding. But in debugger Sphinx doesn't see the new records

Comment: actually when I insert new records in describe before all section Sphinx works otherwise doesn't

Comment: Are you using transactions? Because Sphinx operates as a separate process, you can't use transactions in tests that use Sphinx.

Comment: That is, you can't use transactional fixtures (transactions themselves are just part and parcel of MySQL and PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue. My tmp folder was missing. It solved once i made it.
Thanks